# How to use nchar with like operator in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to use like operator with `nchar(1)` type column, below is my stored procedure:

```
Create procedure [dbo].[CouponSearch]
(
@DiscountType nchar(1)
)as
begin
set nocount on
Select Couponcode from tblCoupons where DiscountType like '%'+@DiscountType+'%'
set nocount off
end
```

I have 2 records in table **tblCoupons**, but I call `proc CouponSearch ''` it return 0 records. TIA.

I have also tried below line but not working as well.

```
 Select Couponcode from tblCoupons where DiscountType like N'%'+@DiscountType+'%'
```

[image]

Comment: Please show us the data in the table, as well as how you call the procedure.

Comment: share the sample output data.

Comment: I have Couponcode  and DiscountType in table ,DiscountType  contains % and $..

Comment: and DiscountType is of type nchar(1)

Comment: @SunilChaudhary : try the `IIF` approach as mentioned in below answer of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this too:

```
DECLARE @DiscountType nchar(1)

SELECT COUPONCODE 
FROM TBLCOUPONS 
WHERE CASE WHEN COALESCE(@DISCOUNTTYPE,'')='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END=1  OR DISCOUNTTYPE = @DISCOUNTTYPE
```

Comment: thanks @etsa, I am using 2008, and it was simple I tried to replace % that is why I totally changed it with like operator..

Comment: @PrabhatG I would say "no", but if you have any evidence of it please let me know.

Comment: @etsa : nevermind. just googled it :) IIF is syntactical sugar for case. cheers.

Comment: @esta what if I want to use it with like operator?

Comment: if you just want change last condition OR DISCOUNTTYPE LIKE ... you can do it.   But if it is CHAR(1) I think it's useless...

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `IIF` condition which handles `''` as well as `NULL`

```
select * from tblCoupons  
where DiscountType = IIF(@DiscountType = '' OR @DiscountType IS NULL,DiscountType,@DiscountType)
```

Hence your procedure becomes :

```
Createprocedure [dbo].[CouponSearch]
(
@DiscountType nchar(1)
)as
begin
set nocount on
Select Couponcode from tblCoupons where DiscountType = IIF(@DiscountType = '' OR @DiscountType IS NULL,DiscountType,@DiscountType)
set nocount off
end
```

Comment: thanks @Prabhat, but i am using 2008, and up-voted you for the efforts..

Answer (score 1):

Or this, For checking null values and Empty String.

Example Source

```
        CREATE TABLE TBLCOUPONS
            (
              Couponid INT ,
              Couponcode VARCHAR(10) ,
              DiscountType NCHAR(1) ,
              Discount INT
            )

        INSERT  TBLCOUPONS
                ( Couponid, Couponcode, DiscountType, Discount )
        VALUES  ( 1, 'JT5326', '$', 5 ),
                ( 2, 'CY1990', '%', 9 )

        GO
```

PROCEDURE

```
        CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CouponSearch] ( @DiscountType NCHAR(1) )
        AS
            BEGIN

                IF ( @DiscountType = '' )
                    BEGIN
                        SET @DiscountType = NULL
                    END

                SELECT  Couponcode
                FROM    tblCoupons
                WHERE   DiscountType = ISNULL(@DiscountType, DiscountType)
            END
            GO
```

EXECUTION

```
    EXEC [CouponSearch] '%'
        GO
        EXEC [CouponSearch] '$'
        GO
        EXEC [CouponSearch] ''
        GO
        EXEC [CouponSearch] NULL
        GO
```

RESULTS

```
         ------------------EXEC [CouponSearch] '%'
        Couponcode
        ----------
        CY1990

        (1 row(s) affected)

         ------------------EXEC [CouponSearch] '$'
        Couponcode
        ----------
        JT5326

        (1 row(s) affected)

         -------------------EXEC [CouponSearch] ''
        Couponcode
        ----------
        JT5326
        CY1990

        (2 row(s) affected)

        -------------------EXEC [CouponSearch] NULL
        Couponcode
        ----------
        JT5326
        CY1990

        (2 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 1):

> IIF() function if you’re using SQL Server 2012:

```
Select Couponcode from tblCoupons where DiscountType = IIF(ISNULL(@DiscountType,'') = '', DiscountType, @DiscountType)
```

> You can make use of a `CASE` statement for the lower versions

```
Select Couponcode from tblCoupons where DiscountType = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@DiscountType,'') = '' THEN DiscountType ELSE @DiscountType END
```